# set a row in prepared statement null

Tags: java, mysql, prepared-statement

```
    if(article.getAttribut() == null ) {
        preparedStatement = initialisationRequetePreparee(connexion,
                SQL_INSERT, true, article.getProduit().getId(), null ,
                article.getDesignationArticle(), article.getArticleParent().getId());
    } else {
            preparedStatement = initialisationRequetePreparee(connexion,
                    SQL_INSERT, true, article.getProduit().getId(), article
                    .getAttribut().getId(),
                    article.getDesignationArticle(), article.getArticleParent().getId());
    }
```

My question is how to set the `article.getAttribut().getId()` on `null` because I got this error

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Parameter index out of range (4 > number of parameters, which is 3).
```

PreparedStatement initialisationRequetePreparee method

```
public static PreparedStatement initialisationRequetePreparee( Connection connexion, String sql, boolean returnGeneratedKeys, Object... objets ) throws SQLException {
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = connexion.prepareStatement( sql, returnGeneratedKeys ? Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS : Statement.NO_GENERATED_KEYS );
        for ( int i = 0; i < objets.length; i++ ) {
            preparedStatement.setObject( i + 1, objets[i] );
        }
        return preparedStatement;
    }
```

Comment: Could you show us the initialisationRequetePreparee method ?

Comment: it looks like ,, you are trying to set value more then 4 while you have only 4-question mark into query...

Comment: please edit your question to include that - togehter with SQL string where we all are waiting to count ? in

Comment: Post Insert query plz

Comment: The error message is complaining that you're assigning a value to the 4th statement parameter, but the SQL statement (in `SQL_INSERT`?) only has 3 parameter markers (`?`), hence the error text *"Parameter index out of range (**4** > number of parameters, which is **3**)"*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `PreparedStatement` there is a method

```
void setNull(int parameterIndex, int sqlType) throws SQLException
```

You can use that method to set a value to `null`

**Note:** Your error is different. Is not related on how to set a value to `null`, instead *is related to the number of parameters you need to set*.
It seems that you have less parameters than the number of actual values you are trying to setting! The number of parameters is equals to the number of `?` present in your query. Probably you have only 3 question marks on your query and you are setting the 4th (not existing) value.

I imagine that the `SQL_INSERT` has a different sql if the `article.getAttribut()` is `null` or not. If this is the situation you can't use a single `initialisationRequetePreparee`. You need two functions or you need a logic internal to `initialisationRequetePreparee` similar to the following:

```
PreparedStatement ps = ...

if (articleAttribute == null) {
    // 3 ps.set functions
} else {
    // 4 ps.set functions
}
return ps;
```

Comment: Thanks for your response .

Comment: You are wellcome. Try to check always the description of the exceptions you have. They tell you your real problem.